# Loop through images, detect if contains color, put in subfolder

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, command-line, imagemagick

I have two kinds of images in my folder: One is all black, the other one is black with yellow (#f8fa27). I am trying to put all the images with yellow colour in a subfolder. But I don't know how this is applicable.

I would like to implement this with ImageMagick or FFMPEG. If possible, shell is redundant and I would like the loop via CMD. If you happen to know of another option that also works, that's no problem either.

I've read about https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php but I don't know how to apply it with my poor skills.

Edit for now I managed to fix it with python (shitty code but it works)

```
import cv2
import os
import glob

#check if extension is png
for filename in glob.glob("*.png"):
    #return to folder where all images are saved
    os.chdir('C:/Users/.../.../images')
    #make image black and white
    image = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
    #if image is fully black
    if cv2.countNonZero(image) == 0:
        print ("Black image, skipped")
    else:
        #colored image
        print ("Colored image")
        #restore true colors (rgb in my case, check wiki)
        image = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        #folder to save colored images
        os.chdir(os.getcwd()+"/yellow")
        #save image to subfolder
        cv2.imwrite(filename,image)
```

Thank you :) !

Comment: Please share a sample of each image. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if an image is all uniformly black, rgb(0,0,0), in ImageMagick using a ternary test for the mean=0 as follows:

```
test=$(convert image.suffix -format "%[fx:mean==0?1:0]" info:)
if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then 
echo "fully black"
else
echo "not fully black"
```

If it is uniformly some other color, then test for std=0:

```
test=$(convert image.suffix -format "%[fx:standard-deviation==0?1:0]" info:)
if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then 
echo "uniform color"
else
echo "not uniform color"
```

So yellow in the black image would fail.

If you black is not uniform, then pick some threshold in the range (0<=thresh<=1)) and do

```
test=$(convert image.suffix -format "%[fx:mean<$thresh?1:0]" info:)
if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then 
echo "fully black"
else
echo "not fully black"
```